# Example Of A Non-Existent Retract

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am looking for an example that disproves the claim that given any subspace $A$ of a topological space $X$, there exists a retract of $X$ onto $A$.

Comment: $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: How about the closed unit disk and the unit circle?

Comment: Oh, duh, of course. Silly me. Thank you.

Comment: not silly -- its not at all obvious unless you think about it in terms of $\pi_1$.  $X$ retracts onto $A$ only if $\pi_1(A)$ is a subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: That's true. But I was thinking indeed about it in terms of the fundamental group, so recalling that the homomorphism induced by the inclusion map is an injection if the space retracts onto some subspace makes this example clear immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the simplest possible example:

Consider the space $X$ with three points $a,b,c$ and open sets $$\emptyset, \{a\},\{c\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,b,c\}.$$ Let $A=\{a,c\}$. There are only two maps from $X$ to $A$ which are the identity on $A$, and neither is continuous. E.g. if we send $b$ to $a$, then the preimage of the open set $\{a\}$ is the non-open set $\{a,b\}$.

This really is the simplest example, since any space retracts onto any of its singleton subsets and onto itself.

Comment: This is my favorite kind of answer to general topology questions, +1! Why get $\pi_1$ involved if you don't have to? But I think $A$ should be $\{a,c\}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks, and quite right - fixed!

Comment: @AlexKruckman  yeah, this is a better answer. but note that this is just using $\pi_0$ instead of $\pi_1$.

Answer (score 2):

A retract of a Hausdorff space is closed so $(0,1)$ is not a retract of $\mathbb{R}$ (usual topology).